# C execute python script via a system call

Tags: python, c

I cannot figure out how I can execute a python script from my C code. I read that I can embed the python code inside C, but I want simply to launch a python script as if I execute it from command line. I tried with the following code:

```
char * paramsList[] = {"/bin/bash", "-c", "/usr/bin/python", "/home/mypython.py",NULL};
pid_t pid1, pid2;
int status;

pid1 = fork();
if(pid1 == -1)
{
    char err[]="First fork failed";
    die(err,strerror(errno));
}
else if(pid1 == 0)
{  
    pid2 = fork();

    if(pid2 == -1)
    {
        char err[]="Second fork failed";
        die(err,strerror(errno));
    }
    else if(pid2 == 0)
    {  
           int id = setsid();
           if(id < 0)
           {
               char err[]="Failed to become a session leader while daemonising";
            die(err,strerror(errno));
           }
           if (chdir("/") == -1)
           {
            char err[]="Failed to change working directory while daemonising";
            die(err,strerror(errno));
        }
        umask(0);

        execv("/bin/bash",paramsList); // python system call          

    }
    else
    {        
        exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
    }
}
else
{    
    waitpid(pid1, &status, 0);
}
```

I don't know where the error is since if I replace the call to python script with the call to another executable, it works well.
I have added at the beginning of my python script the line:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
```

What can I do?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Can you skip the bash call entirely and just call python, like [this](https://gist.github.com/miku/499c5bd2b903d6885448#file-snippet-c-L9)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the Bash [man page](http://manpages.debian.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=bash&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=Debian+7.0+wheezy&format=html&locale=en):

> ```
> -c string   If the -c option is present, then commands are read
>             from string. If there are arguments after the string,
>             they are assigned to the positional parameters,
>             starting with $0.
> ```

E.g.

```
$ bash -c 'echo x $0 $1 $2' foo bar baz
x foo bar baz
```

You, however don’t want to assign to the positional parameters, so change your `paramList` to

```
char * paramsList[] = { "/bin/bash", "-c",
                        "/usr/bin/python /home/mypython.py", NULL };
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `char * paramsList[] = {"/usr/bin/python", "/tmp/bla.py",NULL};` and `execv("/usr/bin/python",paramsList); // python system call` caused a successful invocation of the python script named *bla.py*